# The efficient way to eliminate some elements in a large array

Tags: javascript

I need to have an efficient to clean up a large (about 5000 elements). It consists of numbers and other types of data.

```
var arr = [2, "da", 3, "", dd, 4];
```

I need to have an array with only numbers. So far this is what I have (a test and copy method).

```
    var newArr = [];
    var index = 0;
    for (var k=0; k<arr.length;k++) {
        var ele = arr[k];
        if (!isNaN(parseFloat(ele)) && isFinite(ele)) {
            newArr[index++] = ele;
        } 
    }
    return newArr;
```

Comment: filter method? arr.filter( (el) => isNumber(el) )

and implement isNumber as simple function checking whether element is Number :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.filter()` function:

```js
var arr = [2, "da", 3, "", 'dd', 4, -4],
    newArr = arr.filter(function (v) {
        return Number(v) && isFinite(v);
    });

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It is concise and easy to understand. Do you happen to know which answer is faster on a large array? Yours and the from Kornflexx?

Comment: This function is 30% faster than mine with enourmous array (size > 100000)

Comment: @curious1, I guess, it can be a matter of preference. Try to find the balance between the readability, convenience and performance

Answer (score 2):

This should be efficient.

```
var newArr = arr.slice(); // copy the array, this is optionnal depending of the context
for (var k=arr.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
    if (isNaN(arr[k]) || !isFinite(arr[k])) {
        newArr.splice(k, 1); // replace by arr if you don't copy the array
    } 
}
return newArr;
```